# How to send 'n' Number of packets using TcpClient using c#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, server, tcpclient

I am trying to send multiple packets using TcpClient. this code works on the first iteration. but after the first iteration the server isn't receiving anything(although the loop keeps iterating). server-side code is working fine as I have been testing it with packet sender. Anything to send burst of packets using TcpClient?

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(localIpAddress,localPort);
            tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
            tcpClient.Connect(remoteIpAddress,remotePort);
            Stream stream=tcpClient.GetStream();
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Message {0} Sent",i);
                stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message))));
                stream.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                
            }
```

Comment: packets are how TCP is *implemented* but as a user, you should be entirely ignorant of them. The abstraction that TCP exposes is an *endless stream of bytes*. If you want to break that stream up into packets or messages, it's up to *you* to implement such framing atop the endless stream of bytes (or move to a higher level protocol that does that for you)

Answer (score 0):

You can't accurately control sending of packets using TcpClient.  In fact you can't even do it with a TCP Socket().  You'd need to use a Raw Socket and structure your own TCP packets.

The TCP stack decides when it's going to send a packet based on the socket configuration options, how much information is in the buffer, when the last ACK was, what the window size is, what the RTT is and a few other things.

You can fudge it, by sending lots of data, which will force the TCP stack to send them immediately as fast as it can.  You can also set the `TcpClient.NoDelay()` but this will not work for multiple successive writes unless you have a reasonable delay between writes and even then it is not gauranteed.

You can make low level calls to work out how many packets were sent/recv, but you can only influence this by tweaking the parameters of the TCP stack and even then it will never be deterministic due to the fact the IP is a lossy protocol and TCP packets will go missing and need to be retransmitted.

Your problem with the code above is that you're setting a LocalEndPoint with this line:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(localIpAddress,localPort);
```

The port will not be reusable until the Socket has passed through the `TIME_WAIT` phase which, depending on how the socket shutdown could be 120seconds.

Change that line to:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
```

Or if you must set the source IP address

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(localIpAddress,0);
```

You can read about the `TIME_WAIT` [here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination.htm) and why it is an intrinsic part of the TCP Protocol.

As a side note, `stream.Flush();` or `NetworkStream.Flush()` does absolutely nothing.  This is it's implementation in the .Net source:

```
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>
    ///       Flushes data from the stream.  This is meaningless for us, so it does nothing.
    ///    </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public override void Flush() {
    }
```

Comment: Actually what i am trying to is i am developing a packet sender that only uses single port to send packets. so any help in terms on code changes would be appreciated!!

Comment: If you want to set the source port, and you want to start a new connection each time, then you will need to wait for the old connection to time out from the TCP stack before you can reuse it.  This is by design and part of the TCP protocol.

Comment: why would i have to wait for old connection to finish when i just have to send multiple packets on the same connection?

Comment: The link I have included above explains the tear-down process, the delay is part of the TCP stack.   You cannot avoid this if you want to reuse a source port before the TIME_WAIT has expired and that could be from 0sec to 120sec depending on how the socket shutdown occurred on the network.